# @font-face не работает на армянском языке

Tags: шрифты

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

не работает на армянском языке, но на английском все нормально. Что мне сделать?

Comment: Добавить subset в шрифт. В шрифте точно есть соответствующие глифы?

Comment: Какой шрифт?...

Comment: font-family: 'Arial Black', sans-serif

Comment: Похоже, что вашего алфавита нет в этом шрифте (при проверке, например, тут https://www.fonts-online.ru/font/Arial-Black выводит квадраты)

Comment: Спасибо большое...

Comment: @br3t на указанном сайте может лежать ограниченный набор (например только латиница или латиница + кириллица)

Comment: А вот и информация "от производителя" https://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=1709 Нету не только армянского диапазона. Много чего нету

Comment: @tutankhamun , я изначально смотрел тут https://www.fonts.com/font/monotype/arial , там, правда, обычный Arial, и там букв не было.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зайдите на сайт [www.caniuse.com](http://www.caniuse.com), там про всё можно узнать!

```html
@font-face{
    font-family:Arial;
    src: url("путь к шрифту");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В вашем файле со шрифтами скорее всего нет нужного набора символов. Попробуйте использовать другой шрифт, который поддерживает нужный вам язык. Например, большой выбор бесплатных и качественных шрифтов есть у Google (https://fonts.google.com/). Из близкого к Arial Black попробуйте Open Sans, там схожее Bold начертание.